# How to select a specific column from a multiIndex dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, multi-index

Playing the kaggle beer review datasets

https://www.kaggle.com/rdoume/beerreviews

```
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1504037 entries, 1586613 to 39648
Data columns (total 13 columns):
brewery_id            1504037 non-null int64
brewery_name          1504037 non-null object
review_time           1504037 non-null int64
review_overall        1504037 non-null float64
review_aroma          1504037 non-null float64
review_appearance     1504037 non-null float64
review_profilename    1504037 non-null object
beer_style            1504037 non-null object
review_palate         1504037 non-null float64
review_taste          1504037 non-null float64
beer_name             1504037 non-null object
beer_abv              1504037 non-null float64
beer_beerid           1504037 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(6), int64(3), object(4)
memory usage: 160.6+ MB
```

I just did a pivot table and returns the following results

```
review_stat_by_beer = df[['beer_name','review_overall','review_aroma','review_appearance','review_palate','review_taste']]\
    .drop_duplicates(['beer_name'])\
    .pivot_table(index="beer_name", aggfunc=("count",'mean','median'))


review_stat_by_beer.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 44075 entries, ! (Old Ale) to 葉山ビール (Hayama Beer)
Data columns (total 15 columns):
(review_appearance, count)     44075 non-null int64
(review_appearance, mean)      44075 non-null float64
(review_appearance, median)    44075 non-null float64
(review_aroma, count)          44075 non-null int64
(review_aroma, mean)           44075 non-null float64
(review_aroma, median)         44075 non-null float64
(review_overall, count)        44075 non-null int64
(review_overall, mean)         44075 non-null float64
(review_overall, median)       44075 non-null float64
(review_palate, count)         44075 non-null int64
(review_palate, mean)          44075 non-null float64
(review_palate, median)        44075 non-null float64
(review_taste, count)          44075 non-null int64
(review_taste, mean)           44075 non-null float64
(review_taste, median)         44075 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(10), int64(5)
memory usage: 5.4+ MB
```

Trying to choose these columns

```
review_stat_by_beer.(review_appearance, count)  # SyntaxError: invalid syntax

review_stat_by_beer[(review_appearance, count)] #NameError: name 'review_appearance' is not defined

review_stat_by_beer['(review_appearance, count)'] #KeyError: '(review_appearance, count)'
```

how do I select these pivot table results? My ultimate goal is to do the math between 2 columns:

```
(review_overall, mean) minus (review_taste, mean)
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Try `review_stat_by_beer[('review_appearance', 'count')]`

Comment: it works! THank you! @cs95 wanna make a post so that i can vote for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options for selecting a specific result from a multiIndex:

```
# Setup
df =  pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3))
df.columns = [['A', 'A', 'B'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
df

   A     B
   a  b  c
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
2  6  7  8
```

Direct selection,

```
df[('A', 'a')]

0    0
1    3
2    6
Name: (A, a), dtype: int64
```

Via `loc`,

```
df.loc[:, ('A', 'a')]
# or 
# df.loc(axis=1)[('A', 'a')]  

0    0
1    3
2    6
Name: (A, a), dtype: int64
```

And also with `xs`,

```
df.xs(('A', 'a'), axis=1)

0    0
1    3
2    6
Name: (A, a), dtype: int64
```

The idea in all these cases is to pass a *tuple* of strings which signifies the first and second levels respectively (your column index has 2 levels). In your case that would look like

```
review_stat_by_beer[('review_appearance', 'count')]
```

There are more methods, but these are the best ones.